# Autostarting Python Script Can't Open txt File, DoubleClicking it Works Fine

Tags: linux, python, xubuntu, autostart

So I have a Python 2.7 script and I'm running xubuntu. When I run the script by double clicking it, everything works fine. However, I recently added it to the autostart menu and it runs but once it's time to read from a txt file (using open()) the program crashes. Anyone know what is causing this?

I want my script to run from autostart just as it does from double clicking or terminal.

Comment: what does it means that "program crashes"? Please, provide more info.

Comment: Program stops working and closes when the time comes for it to read from a txt file.